# How can I set such "track" link in gmail?

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, gmail

I saw the following "Track order" link in Flipkart's order confirmation mail (gmail):

[image: Screenshot]

How do I acheive this? I don't know what it is called, so don't know what to search for. I apologize if this question is already asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using an Email Schema via [schema.org](http://schema.org/).

Google uses this service to allow rich markup of emails (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/overview)

You will need to register with Google and comply with their guidelines in order to use a schema in an email to provide a deep-link to your website.

The guidelines are located here: [Registering with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google#registration_guidelines)

In Summary:

- Emails must be authenticated with SPF or DKIM
- Emails must come from a static address and must follow Google's [Bulk Sender Guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en)
- The link must be to a specific page on your website and the label should clearly reflect the intent of the action

There's a few more, but these are the main requirements. Once you comply, you need to email schema.whitelisting+sample@gmail.com to allow Google to ensure you comply with the requirements and white list your domain for deep-linking.

Comment: This is what I was looking for exactly:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action#track_action.

I was able to navigate from your answer, thanks.